# Confirm Form ReSubmission Bypass

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, joomla

In need of a bit of help. On my website if you click on a property on the main page then click the "Back to Search Results" link at the top it takes you back to the homepage. Yet if you go to say page 4 and click on a property then click on the "Back to Search Results" it comes up with an error saying "Confirm Form Resubmission".

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem for some extent.

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no cache'); //no cache

session_cache_limiter('must-revalidate');
?>
```